# Bounties page updates with new activity for non bounty questions

Tags: bug, status-norepro, bounty, new-nav, live-refresh

I was browsing the bounties page for the [Python tag here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/need-answers/python?show=bounties&sort=ending&pageSize=30), and opened a few links to go look at them. I left the page of bounties open, and after a few minutes noticed a `(4)` appear in the tab's title indicating 4 new entries. I thought it was pretty unlikely that 4 new bounties had cropped up, so I took a look and when I clicked on the "4 questions have new activity" button it just expanded some generic new questions that were tagged [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python).

Thankfully while waiting on this a new one did also crop up so I have a couple screenshots:

[image: Questionable Bounties]

---

[image]

They seem to be newest questions as they match the exact questions on the 'Newest' tab I also have open. It also rights itself when I refresh the page so it's just when updating that the problem occurs.

Comment: I don't understand. For me the link for Python tag in this post doesn't work and tabs for tags are named completely different than in the screenshot. How do you even get to this page?

Comment: @eis: You're signed up for new-nav alpha testing, right?

Comment: Cross-site dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263993/when-viewing-bounties-non-bounty-questions-should-not-appear-via-the-1-new-que.

Comment: @NathanTuggy didn't know about such a thing. I see the tag now when you mention it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should be fixed now, but please double check

Comment: Yeah, left it open for a few hours and had no problems.